# Multiply randomints from Input?

Tags: python, random

```
    import random

def Dice():
    num_dice = raw_input("How many dice are you rolling? ")
    user_dice = raw_input("How many sides do you want on your dice? ")
    user_diceint = int(user_dice)
    dice_rolling1 = random.randint(0, user_diceint)
    print dice_rolling, "was your dice roll."



    if user_dice > 0 and user_dice.isdigit():
        print "This is correct."
        if len(num_dice) <= 0:
            num_dice = 2
            print num_dice, "is the number of dice you rolled"
            print num_dice * user_dice, "is your total roll"
        else:
            print "Number of Dice has an error"
    else:
        print "This is not a number."
```

So I am new to coding/programming and I thought I would try my hand at doing a Dice roll generator. So in the code I have num_dice which is the number of dice("duh"). But I was wondering how would I do a different randint for each of the dice. So say someone enters '5' dice. How would I get my code to generate 5 different randomints to simulate 5 actual dice being rolled? Would some kind of loop work for this? Please excuse the bad code, I am new and it's still being worked on! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `for` loop in your `Dice` function to handle that

```
def Dice():
    num_dice = int(raw_input("How many dice are you rolling? "))
    user_dice = int(raw_input("How many sides do you want on your dice? "))
    for roll in range(1, num_dice+1):
        dice_roll = random.randint(1, user_dice)
        print "Roll number", roll, "was: ", dice_roll
```

Example

```
num_dice = 5     # 5 rolls
user_dice = 8    # 8 sided dice
```

Output

> Roll number 1 was:  2
>   Roll number 2 was:  1
>   Roll number 3 was:  8
>   Roll number 4 was:  4
>   Roll number 5 was:  6

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a list of rolling dice `num_dice` times:

```
list_of_values = [random.randint(0, user_diceint) for _ in range(num_dice)]
```

#### Your Code

```
def Dice():
    num_dice = raw_input("How many dice are you rolling? ")
    user_dice = raw_input("How many sides do you want on your dice? ")
    user_diceint = int(user_dice)
    list_of_values = [random.randint(0, user_diceint) for _ in range(num_dice)]
    print list_of_values, "were your dice rolls."
```